# Object operators in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

A noob question

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

The above line is taken from indexController's init method in a tutorial that I have been following. Does the code sample really mean execute "setNoRender" method from viewRenderer object from _helper object from zend_Controller_Action object? Or is there a code writing convention specific to zend framework that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a zend convention. Its a PHP syntax.

$this refers to current obj. 
Using -> operator you can access its properties or methods.

> Does the code sample really mean execute "setNoRender" method from
>   viewRenderer object from _helper object from zend_Controller_Action
>   object?

Yes you are correct.

> $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

This will disable the view, it is very useful when you using an ajax request.

FYI: [Zend Controller action](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.introduction)

> The primary reasons to disable the ViewRenderer are if you simply do
>   not need a view object or if you are not rendering via view scripts
>   (for instance, when using an action controller to serve web service
>   protocols such as SOAP, XML-RPC, or REST). In most cases, you will
>   never need to globally disable the ViewRenderer, only selectively
>   within individual controllers or actions.

Comment: Thanks Venu for the detailed answer!